# How do I expand the camera frame on the Y axis?

Tags: camera, transforms

I was following this guy's tutorial on how to make a leaf shader and on one of the steps he changed the camera frame into a square. I'm trying to-do that, so it'll match the bounds reference of the empty square, but I don't know how to extend it along the Y axis even though I tried using the scale it didn't seem to work. [image]

Comment: In *Output Properties* you can adjust the Resolution X & Y which will change your camera dimension. If you want sqaure change it to something like 1000x1000

Comment: Also consider changing the "Sensor Fit" setting in Camera settings to control which dimension is adjusted as you modify the output resolution.